# How to say my meetings have caused cascading delay

Tags: phrasal-verbs, time

What is another way to say to co-workers that my previous meeting took longer than expected (and hence I am late for the current meeting).

and what is the business and also day to day common phrase(s) (or phrasal verbs) for saying that one of my meetings took longer than expected and it has had a cascading effect on the meetings after it, causing me to be late to the current meeting?

Answer (score 4):

A day to day phrase?

> My meeting took longer than expected and it has had a **domino
> effect** on the meetings after it.

**domino effect**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Domino) an idiom

> A phenomenon in which an initial event causes a series of other
> related events to occur, much like the sequence seen in toppling
> dominos

Like a self sustaining reaction or a chain reaction  (figuratively).

Answer (score 1):

If you want a phrasal verb, I can suggest "set back"

> phrasal verb
>   1.If something sets you back or sets back a project or scheme, it causes a delay.
>   [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/set-back)
>
> set someone/something back
>   1.Delay or impede the progress of someone or something.
>  [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/set)

"set back" by itself may be OK, but I personally think that using the word timetable or schedule with it is a lot better.

- "The last meeting ran late, and now my whole schedule has been set back. I apologize."

Or possibly "one of my meetings" instead of "last meeting".

Comment: +1 This is the phrasing I would have heard from the pediatrician.  I can imagine her saying, "I was called to the hospital first thing this morning, and that set everything back.  I've been playing catch-up all day."